# My Browser Console is Error Free But Its is stops the jquery version to load bootstrap model pop up

Tags: javascript

I have added a pop up on Click of Change Password Tab and appointments ,
Please help me what is the problem in my js file custome.js , since i have tried this in js  validator for syntax checking it is absolutely fine , no error in console.

All Custom Js is Working Fine. But Bootstrap Model is not Working Once I remove my custome.js file the bootstrap model perfeclty works.

https://mobulous.app/clinicnew/

Comment: did you try `$('#id').modal('show');`

Comment: i have added on Change Password Tab At Left :


data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"

But Its Not Showing Any Bug...

Comment: There is no event in your `custome.js` file to start the modal as @Edison said. If you try in the console: `$('#myModal').modal()` it shows the modal. You just need to read the bootstrap [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-usage) and you should be fine.

Comment: @user3021146 just try making a function to show it

Comment: Do i need to add something under option , Its says uncaught 
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: "no error in console" doesn't mean "no error" in javascript....  (one of the 'gotchas' of that particular language...)  If you remove your custom.js and all works, and have it there, you get a 'silent' crash, then there is something not right in there - and JS just doesn't tell you about it (frustrating, I know... :)  Your js is not on your page - and you should put it in your question so others will give you help (I would not normally click on some link - many others won't either)

Comment: Thanks For Your Valuable help that means a lot for me..

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed in your header you are using bootstrap 3 I would suggest moving to the latest version

Use the CDNS which can be found [here](https://getbootstrap.com/) or as posted below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also, add your custom JS into the head with all the other scripts.

[Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) is the bootstrap documentation on modals. Going over this will help you understand how to use the modals better.

However if for any reason you need to use bootstrap 3 try this example -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/custome.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Modal Example</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
    
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```